# AWS ECS Docker Server Connect to ElastiCache Redis

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

A node server is running on Fargate ECS. The server needs to connect to a Redis database when it starts using node-redis.

The ECS service and the ElasticCache Redis is in the same VPC, and they are in the same private IP range (10.0.0.x, 10.0.0.y).

However, connection timeout error is always returned.

Also, I created a EC2 instance within the same VPC, and successfully connected to the Redis service.

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: What security group rules does the ElastiCache server have?

Comment: Thanks for reply, the SG accepts all traffic inbound from the ECS